# Please vote: Do we want an AI warning banner?

Tags: discussion, featured, status-review

<sub>This could be considered to be a follow-up of [AI generated content is problematic](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/4762)</sub>

---

Can I draw your attention to this post on SE.Meta, [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/280335).

In short:

- There <strike>are two banners</strike> is one banner to choose from:

  - `**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more`
  - <strike>`**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more`</strike>
- We need to reach a per-site concensus, and then we can notify the CM team of our intention

So, there seem to be <strike>three</strike> two options:

- No banner
- AI is not allowed
- <strike>AI must be cited</strike>

Please vote accordingly on the answers below.

Votes will be counted on April 1 2024, and the results taken at that date (unless there are any objections).

---

##### Citation is now default

Note: The citation is now by default, see this update, [Proposed changes to Help Center articles to include mention of AI-generated content policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/280335).

So, basically, the question now is whether to allow AI or not...

Comment: Maybe, there should be an option to ban AI but **not** have the banner - as *yet another* banner could be considered "just more clutter" on an already crowded UI..?

Answer (score 5):

#### AI not allowed

Vote for this, if you want the banner to say

```
**Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more
```

Comment: Obviously I can not vote on my own posts, but this option is my preference

Comment: If the complete answer is generated by AI through a prompt inquiry, I fully support this (see e.g. [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/23061/). However, those who wrote their own answer, but improve the text through AI should be tolerated, not everyone is proficient in English.

Answer (score 0):

#### No banner

Vote for this, if you do not want any banner at all.